# my react app goes white if i add component={Link} in <Tab> component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After adding component={Link} in  component. My react screen goes completely white, but when I not add Link component then it works fine.

```
<Tabs textColor="inherit" value={value} onChange={(e,val)=>setValue(val)}>
              <Tab component={Link} to="/blogs" label="All Blogs"/>
              <Tab label="My Blogs"/>
</Tabs>
```

and If I don't add Link component, then react page works. what' s the problem here ?

Comment: Are you sure you're properly importing the Link component? Check the console for errors. There's a million reasons why a React app can't render properly so we just need a bit more context to be able to help.

Comment: Check the console and let me know If you find any issues there..

Comment: sorry, my bad. I didn't wrap BrowserRouter to this component in App.js . My issue is resolved. All I had to do was wrap this component inside BrowserRouter

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
<Tab component={<Link/>} to="/blogs" label="All Blogs"/>
```

Comment: sorry, my bad. I didn't wrap BrowserRouter to this component in App.js . My issue is resolved. All I had to do was wrap this component inside BrowserRouter